# Alternativen zu dem Ausdruck „mit jemandem Zeit verbringen“?

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage

> Ich habe gestern mit einer russischen Freundin Zeit verbracht.

Es gibt zwei weitere Verben dafür, aber sie werden umgangssprachlich verwendet.

> Ich habe gestern mit einer russischen Freundin *herumgehangen*.
>
> Ich habe gestern mit einer russischen Freundin *abgehangen*.

Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: Warum suchst du weitere Ausdrücke, für welchen Zweck sind die vorhandenen nicht geeignet? Im Moment sieht es sehr nach *general reference* (Synonymwörterbuch) aus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not translate "I spent time with my girl friend" literally; it sounds weird. Auf Deutsch sagt man eher "Ich war bei meiner Freundin" oder sagt genauer, was man gemacht hat, z.B. "ich war mit meiner Freundin im Kino".

Wenn man sagt "ich habe den ganzen Tag bei meiner Freundin verbracht" klingt das fast wie etwas unangenehmes oder wie Arbeit (ich musste soooo viel Zeit investieren). Oder es klingt wie ein Alibi, wenn die Polizei fragt.

Answer (score 1):

"Herumhängen" kann schnell mal mit "Nichtstun" in Verbindung gebracht werden: "Hör auf den ganzen Tag nur herumzuhängen!".

> Gestern bin ich zusammen mit einer russischen Freundin abgehangen.

Hört sich in dem Fall für mich schon besser an. Allerdings werden beide Phrasen fast ausschließlich im Kontext mit Jugendlichen verwendet.

Weitere Beispiele wären:

> Gestern war ich mit einer russischen Freundin zusammen.
>   Gestern war ich mit einer russischen Freundin beisammen.

unüblich, aber möglich:

> Gestern war ich mit einer russischen Freundin beieinander.

Comment: Die Sätze mit _beisammen_ und _beieinander_ sind für mich ungrammatisch.

Comment: Meine Muttersprache ist Deutsch und ich wüsste nicht was daran falsch ist, aber ich lasse mich natürlich gerne belehren :)